Lost `snapshots` subvolumes in SLES15; is there a way to recover them?
When inspecting logs for a different issue, I realized that a host had lost its snapshots.
As the event must have been more then 6 months ago, there are no more logs to show details, but the mount for snapshots is missing in /etc/fstab, and no snapshot subvolume is listed by btrfs subvolume list.
Being curious I wonder if I can prove that there ever existed such subvolumes (I'm sure they did), and maybe even recover some of them?
The machine runs x86-64 in a VM, and the issue must have happened somewhere between SLES15 SP3 and SLES15 SP5; currently SLES15 SP6 is running.
